# Linux File Type

Tags: linux, file, directory

I could access the all mounted volumes with "cd/Volumes", and I command "ls -l".
This lists:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root          admin      1 Aug  3 20:05 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 username  staff  16384 Aug  2 16:33 Untitled
-rwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin      0 Jan 23  2014 bin
```

And I just wonder why my usb drive's file type is "d". I thought it should be "b" or "c".
My usb driver's name is Untitled.
I'm learning linux using mac.
Any helps or links are appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you think it should be `b` or `c`? `d` is short for directory, and file systems are mounted as directories in the Unix/Linux world

Comment: I thought "b" or "c" would be used for some hardware to connected mac. I'm just confused...
then what the "b" or "c" are used for? If I connect my printer, it should be "b" or "c"?

Answer (score 0):

From **[ls invocation - What information is listed](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed)**:

```
The file type is one of the following characters: 

‘-’
    regular file
‘b’
    block special file
‘c’
    character special file
‘C’
    high performance (“contiguous data”) file
‘d’
    directory
‘D’
    door (Solaris 2.5 and up)
‘l’
    symbolic link
‘M’
    off-line (“migrated”) file (Cray DMF)
‘n’
    network special file (HP-UX)
‘p’
    FIFO (named pipe)
‘P’
    port (Solaris 10 and up)
‘s’
    socket
‘?’
    some other file type v
```